# Cannot import realm classes in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm using android studio 2.1.3, gradle version 2.1.3 , realm 2.2.1 and java 8

I can import classes like

```
io.realm.Realm;
io.realm.RealmQuery;
io.realm.RealmResults;
```

and project compiles successfully

but I cannot import classes like

```
io.realm.SyncCredentials;
io.realm.ObjectServerError;
io.realm.SyncUser;
```

basically object server related classes.
for some reason studio cannot find those classes. I've included correct code in both the build.gradle files.

any suggestions ?

Comment: show your gradle file

Comment: http://txt.do/dd4tk

Comment: http://txt.do/dd4to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[In order to enable sync classes, you need to enable sync in the Realm plugin.](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#enabling-realm-mobile-platform)

> **Enabling Realm Mobile Platform**
>
> In order to to enable Realm Mobile Platform you must add the following section to your app’s build.gradle:
>
> ```
> realm {
>     syncEnabled = true;
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks. That solved the problem. I had to add it after the dependencies.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce in which block of gradle do we have to put this ??

Comment: Pretty much anywhere, outside of any other blocks? But technically in the same file as where `apply plugin: 'realm-android'` is.

Answer (score 2):

Read this - you need add Realm plugin: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#getting-started

Comment: I've added the plugin in both the files.